# Bash exit code 126 when I POST large amount of data with cURL

Tags: sql, bash, curl, sh

Automated process: I have a SQL View that I convert to JSON, and I'm attempting to POST the JSON via cURL in Bash. This works fine when the View pulls ~50 or fewer records, but if I increase the amount of records the View pulls, and change absolutely nothing else, it breaks on me, exit code 126 instead of 0.

Here's the cURL command I'm trying

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -u "${USER}:${API_KEY}" \
    -o $LOCATION$RESPONSE_FILE_NAME \
    -d "${JSON}" \
    $SERVER
```

Again, this works exactly how I want it to until I increase the size of $JSON. The only thing I touch to do this is one line in my SQL code.

Another process I have utilizes the '--form file=@' option of cURL, and I believe that would solve my problem here, i.e. keep the JSON in a separate file instead of dumping it directly into the cURL command. However, this specific API won't accept the data like that.

Is there any way I can edit my cURL command so it will allow me to deliver up to ~2mb of data in one go? Is that even the problem here, or am I perhaps overlooking something else?

Comment: Can you try `-d "@data.json"` to pass in a file?

Comment: That worked! Thanks, didn't realize that was an option

Comment: @SiKing I think you can add it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [curl man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

> -d/--data

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin. The contents of the file must already be URL-encoded. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar.